# Statsmodels seasonal decomposition - Trend not a straight line

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, decomposition

This query refers to decomposition of classic Airline passengers data into Trend, Seasonal and Residual. We expect linear trend to be a straight line. However, the result is not so. I wonder what is the logic behind extraction of Trend. Can you please throw some light?

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
result = seasonal_decompose(airline['Thousands of Passengers'], model='additive')  
result.plot();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two things to clarify:

1) Not all trends are linear

2) Even linear trends can be subject to some variation depending on the time series in question.

For instance, let's consider the trend for [maximum air temperature](https://www.michael-grogan.com/arima-model-statsmodels-python/) in Dublin, Ireland over a number of years (modelled using statsmodels):

[image: weather]

In this example, you can see that the trend both ascends and descends - given that air temperature is subject to changing seasons we would expect this.

In terms of the airline dataset, we can see that the trend is being observed over a number of years. Even when the observed, seasonal and residual components have been extracted, the trend itself will be subject to shifts over time.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Trying to get around the idea of fluctuating trend. Any idea how the trend is calculated (logic of calculation)?

Comment: Well, a trend is simply calculated by generating a line of best fit for the associated observations, as is the case with standard regression analysis. That said, the example above is taking into account that the shape of a trendline can change over time - as is the case in the real world. Going back to the weather example, if the trendline were to remain constant across all years, then it is likely that one would just observe a straight line. e.g. an average of 15 degrees Celsius, but this wouldn't account for the fact that there are large temperature deviations across winter and summer.

Comment: Following your comments, we should expect the trend to show an average of 15 degree celsius (or a line with slight upward/downward slope) and the deviations across winter and summer due to seasonality. However, the actual logic used is not clear.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the time period in question is decades, then the trend line will shift in the case of a significant change in trend (e.g. if it is significantly colder for a 3-year period compared to the previous 3 years). Indeed, this is what we observe in the weather trend graph. The reason the trend line is not straight in your example (or the case of weather) is that we are dealing with data over a long time period.